# What does the PHP mail Reply-To header do?

Tags: php, email

My PHP Mail headers are:

```
From: Writer's Tryst <admin@writers-tryst.com>
Reply-To: The Charlotte Gusay Literary Agency <rontornambe@yahoo.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.5.37
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

When I click the Gmail "to" button:

[image]

When I reply to this email, the mail is sent to the From address. I expected it to be sent to the Reply-To address. Is there any way to setup PHP mail to accomplish this? The documentation is not clear about what the Reply-To header actually does.

Comment: It is up to the replying client to handle that header as it wishes. Typically a reply should go to the reply-to, but gmail may intentionally refuse to send to the reply-to address in this case because it is on a different domain than the From header's address.  If you can, test a reply to a different address on the same domain as the From. You have no real control over where your recipients' mail clients (e.g. Gmail) choose to direct their replies.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. That what I expected. I will just include the reply-to email address in the body.

Comment: The RFC 2822 spec describes what Reply-To is for - it isn't really up to PHP to do anything other than include the header. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822

Comment: it's when you hit reply it replies to that address

Comment: That is what I would like to think it does, but it doesn't - see Michael's comment.

Comment: Weird. I've never had Gmail refuse to accept a reply-to, but maybe it's the missing SPF or DKIM that the `via` indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Reply-to allows you to assign a different email address to have the email reply to. When php mail function includes the header, it basically becomes a variable that the email-server can assign to the reply button. But many email-server filters reject these when they are not on the same server that the headers were sent from.